# jQuery not deleting cookie before resetting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to use Javascript to update some cookies for a website. It should look to see if an existing cookie as a certain value. If so, delete the cookie and replace it.

Instead, it's adding the new cookie without removing the original.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(getCookie('ref') == 'na') {
    $.cookie('ref', null, { path: '/', expires: -5 });
    $.cookie('ref', Base64.encode(document.referrer), { expires: 365 });
}

});
```

Here's the cookie library I'm  using: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a cookie, you must set it with the exact same path and domain you intend to delete it from.  Specify the `path` in both `$.cookie()` calls, and if the `domain` was specified in any previous code, the domain must be specified as an exact match in the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(getCookie('ref') == 'na') {
      $.cookie('ref', null, { path: '/', expires: -5 });
      $.cookie('ref', Base64.encode(document.referrer), {path: '/', expires: 365 });
  }
});
```

However, there is no real need to delete the cookie if you just intend to overwrite it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(getCookie('ref') == 'na') {
    // Just write the new cookie over the old one...
    $.cookie('ref', Base64.encode(document.referrer), {path: '/', expires: 365 });
  }
 });
```

Comment: i think the path is the problem. When I set the cookie in PHP it's adding a period to the beginning of the domain name. I think that's why JS doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: @liz Yes, the domain like the path must be an exact match when you attempt to overwrite a cookie.